# Convert Date Format in Excel from foreign date

Tags: date-format, excel-2013, date-conversion

I converted a PDF to Excel file and now my date column is being recognized as Danish dates. When I pivot or try to format them, the format stays in Danish.

How can Danish format be converted to English (US)?

I've tried changing the language in Format Cell settings  with no success. Some convert just fine while others don't.

Using TEXT([@Date],"MM/DD/YYYY") the results are:

```
     Original
     05-06-14 
     05-06-14
     05-04-14
     04-30-14
     04-29-14

     Converts to
     06/14/2005
     06/14/2005
     04/14/2005
     04/30/2014 (correct)
     04/29/2014 (correct)
```

Help?

Comment: I'd use string functions in a formula, and output it as a date. Force the first 2 characters to be "month", characters 4 and 5 to be "day", and the 2 right-most characters to be "year".  (I'll come up with a formula in a sec and post it as an Answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It's Easy.. Just select the column.. and change the cell formate by pressing (ctrl+1) and change it to Date.. It will ask 19xx or 20xx.. select the appropriate years.. you'll get it..

I even tried and I get the perfect result what you are actually looking for..

```
        **A**           **B**
        *Number/text*   *Date*
1       05-06-14       =TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/YYYY")
2       05-06-14         
3       05-04-14         
4       04-30-14         
5       04-29-14
```

Repeat the above formula on B1 on bottom rows.. you'll get result..

Otherwise.. you can simply select column A and change the type to Date.. and then follow the step one as i said on top

Comment: actually this worked perfect on my computer. that's why i shared it.. would you mind if i ask you to share your file somewhere.. so i could resolve that.. or atleast share one date column...

Comment: File location: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIaxHNJWVvLdWJIVkJlajBhems/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Were you able to view the file?

Comment: Your first 4 dates in cell column has different format .. some custome date format.. .mm-dd-yy;@  and the rest has different.. what i did.. it's working find on the whole column rest of first 4

Comment: Here is the file.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HoKtyuZxb-dFZSNGZKQXdRWGM/edit?usp=sharing)

 Please check.. you can manually change the date on first 4 cells..  just double click and change it..
secondly.. goto cell format..under date, under location select English(US) and then type above Location .. the one you are looking for.

And lastly.. Excel actually displays what once has created in background. If wrong input and formated.. you need to convert it first simple text, then remove formating etc.. then re-calculate..

Answer (score 0):

If you can format the whole column with the messy values (column "A") as text, and format the next column (column "B") as Date, you can put this formula into the Date-formatted column (column "B").

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&MID(A1,4,2)&"/20"&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Comment: The result is #VALUE!

Comment: Evaluate Formula returns: DATEVALUE("38/17/2017")

Comment: Sorry.  Obviously month can't be "38" or "17", so I'm not sure what else to do with your data....